# How to draw this ER diagram

Tags: database, entity-relationship

How to draw ER diagram for this.
Players plays game.game is controlled by refree. Organizer organizes game and pay to refree. Refree is appointed by federation. Assume your own sets on attributes.

I am trying to see what the er diagram is for this question

Comment: My gf asked me this question. I am trying to impress her. Help?

Comment: Lol i will ..if u give me the solution first